# Trying to elicit a function by defining PDEs and using DSolve / NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I have been struggling trying to figure out how to make either DSolve or NDsolve work for my purposes. I have a function in mind, so I "know" the answer here, but I am trying to figure out how to make Mathematica find it for me. The function is:

```
$Assumptions = a > 0 && b > 0 && 0 <= x <= 1
f[a,b,x]=x^a(1-x)^b
```

I want Mma to find this function by using some of its characteristics:

- x f[a,b,x] = f[a+1,b,x]
- (1-x) f[a,b,x] = f[a,b+1,x]

Now if I were to do this manually, my guess is I could also use results from partial derivatives on a and b, not only on x. But adding these does not seem to help Mma.

Finally, I also tried adding this property:

- f[a,b,x]=f[b,a,1-x]
  But Mma complains about the ordering of parameters not being consistent...

My understanding is that the fact that the a and b parameters become shifted is akin to having a "[Delay Differential Equation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDelayDifferentialEquations.html)", but the help page seems to only provide numerical solutions whereas I am looking for the above closed form. Also, when I use NDsolve, I get this error: "Endpoint b in {a,b,x} is not a real number".

Here is some of the code I am trying out in my notebook:

```
DSolve[{
   D[x f[a, b, x], x] == D[f[a + 1, b, x], x],
  D[(1 - x) f[a, b, x], x] == D[f[a, b + 1, x], x]},
 f[a, b, x], {a, b, x}]
DSolve[{
  D[x f[a, b, x], x] == D[f[a + 1, b, x], x],
  D[(1 - x) f[a, b, x], x] == D[f[a, b + 1, x], x],
  D[f[a, b, x], x] == D[f[b, a, 1 - x], x]},
 f[a, b, x], {a, b, x}]
DSolve[{
   D[x f[a, b, x], a] == D[f[a + 1, b, x], a],
   D[x f[a, b, x], b] == D[f[a + 1, b, x], b],
   D[x f[a, b, x], x] == D[f[a + 1, b, x], x],
  D[(1 - x) f[a, b, x], a] == D[f[a, b + 1, x], a],
  D[(1 - x) f[a, b, x], b] == D[f[a, b + 1, x], b],
  D[(1 - x) f[a, b, x], x] == D[f[a, b + 1, x], x]},
 f[a, b, x], {a, b, x}]
```

I am new to this and realize I am simply throwing stuff in to see what sticks; any pointers to a way to solve this manually and/or via Mma much appreciated.

[EDIT 1]
I have asked a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4618419/solving-a-pde-such-as-frac-partial-partial-xfa1-x-fa-xx-frac-partia) on the math forum in order to focus on usable methods for this problem and decouple the aspect related to the specific functions and uses available in Mathematica with the more basic mathknowledge I am probably missing here.

Comment: As part of what I am missing is also due to me lacking in math tools and knowledge, would it be OK for me to "cross-post" on math.stackexchange the related question as to the method for solving this type of problem (and disclose the link to the cross-post in both posts)?